# Apple Watch NSLog messages not showing up

Tags: xcode, apple-watch, nslog

I'm working on an apple watch app.  When I launch it through the xcode on a real Apple Watch device I don't get any of my NSLog messages that are in my Apple Watch code.  Is there a way to fix it so that they will show up?  I can use break points and the debugging for Apple Watch code works so I know xcode is connected to the process but none of my the NSLog messages from the Watch code appear.